# Excluded folders In IntelliJ Idea

Tags: android, mercurial, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ Idea for Android development and IntelliJ uses a folder named `out` for putting APK file.

I am also using Mercurial as VCS and when I clone the project the out folder is left out from the cloned directory.

Also folder out is also not shown in the project structure and when I go to Open Module Settings -> Modules the folder is excluded as shown in the image below

[image]

Why out folder is excluded and how to include it in VCS (Mercurial)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why out folder is excluded

Because this folder doesn't contain sources and (I suppose) IntelliJ mirror own settings into .hgignore file of related repository

> how to include it in VCS (Mercurial)?

Just

## Never do it

because versioning of build artifacts is bad idea, useless, wasted time and space - save only sources, not repeatable results

but, if you want to try all racks on the way - remove the related string from .hgignore.

Comment: +1, could not find any file named .hgignore. I am using Windows 7.

Comment: @codingcrow - if you haven't .hgignore in the root of repo, it may be per-user (not per-repo) ignore patterns file, defined in mercurial.ini, [ui] section, "ignore" key

Comment: Ok, I found the file mercurial.ini int he user but the file has only one line `# Generated by TortoiseHg settings dialog`

Comment: @codingcrow - try to find **all** Mercurial's configs (I haven't Mercurial on Win7), maybe [this link](http://www.selenic.com/hg/help/config) can help. Quote from text "Mercurial reads configuration data from several files, if they exist.
    These files do not exist by default and you will have to create the
    appropriate configuration files yourself: global configuration like the
    username setting is typically put into "%USERPROFILE%\mercurial.ini" or
    "$HOME/.hgrc" and local configuration is put into the per-repository
    "<repo>/.hg/hgrc" file."

Comment: @codingcrow - File-paths: `(Windows) "%USERPROFILE%\.hgrc"
    (Windows) "%USERPROFILE%\Mercurial.ini"
    (Windows) "%HOME%\.hgrc"
    (Windows) "%HOME%\Mercurial.ini"`

Comment: I have checked all the possible configuration file and could not find a configuration ignoring the out folder.